# Android layout is not being displayed when input is required

Tags: android

I have an app that uses several activities. One activity is to manually enter some values and I have four buttons in that activity. When one of the buttons is clicked it starts a new activity to get the input.

The problem is that the layout for the activity is not displayed when the get_input() function of this activity is run. It should get a decimal value from an EditText. but I keep getting a runtime error of "Invalid Float """.

If I comment out the get_input() function then the layout for the activity is shown fine.

Here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/manually_entry" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Please enter the decimal Latitude"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Negative is South"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
        android:id="@+id/enter_decimal_number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the calling activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.lat_long_manual_entry);

}

// manual entry dialog buttons
public void enter_lat_dec_deg(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ManuallyEnterNumbers.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}


And here is the called activity that requests the actual input from the user :

    package com.example.david.gpstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by david on 06/03/16.
 */
public class ManuallyEnterNumbers extends Activity {

    private EditText input;

    private float decimal_input;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.manually_enter_numbers);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        get_input();
     }


        public void get_input() {

            input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_decimal_number);
            input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        decimal_input = Float.valueOf(input.getText().toString());

                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    }

}
```

I am showing the function get_input() in the onStart() method but IO have also tried it in the onResume() method and that does not work either.

Any help here would be very much appreciated.

```
                 Thank You.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Float.valueOf(input.getText().toString());

The common mistake here newbies ofter make is lack of string sanitization prior attempting conversion. Even `,` (comma) instead of `.` (dot) entered as decimal part separator will cause exception to be thrown. So you simply must make string convertable (i.e. by checking what's inside, replacing `,` with `.` etc) not to mention you should expect exception to come and use `try/catch` to catch it to avoid app crash you are facing now.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am using the soft keyboard, and the xml for the EditText has `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"` so the only characters that can be entered are the digits 0 to 9, dot, space minus and comma. So the text is partially sanitised anyway. The main problem is getting the input actually entered. I have discovered that I need a listener for the EditText. I have amended the code of the original question to show what I have now and this is working better. The problem now is that the activity is not recognising the "Done" key on the soft keyboard.

Comment: `inputType` does not matter for `Double` class - sanitize your string prior converting. And leave DONE key for now. Fix one thing at a time.

Comment: thank you for your reply. What is a Double class ? My decimal_input variable is defined as a float not a double. And I defined the inputType to restrict the characters that the user could enter. Because stack overflow has a limit on the number of characters that you can put in a comment I truncated the original error message. The actual original error message was invalid float "". So that tells me that there is no input (empty string). I would have thought that there is no real point in sanitising an empty string.

Comment: By `Double` I meant `Float`, sorry

Comment: I said already - SANITIZE AND CHECK your input string prior attempting conversion. There's no point to discussing this further. Really. Trust me.

Comment: Sorry if I have upset you. I didn't mean to. Can you please explain where I should put the code to sanitise the input because when I debug the project in Android Studio my app fails when it tries to enter the `input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()` method. Sorry for the late reply but I am having a bit of a domestic crisis here at the moment.           Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

David, hello, this is yourself. Basically you can forget about sanitizing the input. Because you have `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"` in your xml you will get a numeric keypad with the comma, and space disabled. So all that the user can enter is digits a decimal point and a minus sign. Exactly what you want. Secondly, you can forget about the `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods and stick everything in `onCreate()` and then it will work. Your xml is absolutely fine. Your calling activity absolutely fine too although it would be a good idea to use an `intent.putExtra()` and an `intent.getExtra()` to pass the decimal_input value back to the calling activity. I have posted the code for the calling activity and the called activity below to help you out a bit.

```
    public class ManualEntry extends Activity {

//    private View layout;

//    private PopupWindow enter_manual_dec_deg;

//    LayoutInflater inflater;


//    private EditText input;

//    private float decimal_input;

//    private String result;

    static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    String button_pressed;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.lat_long_manual_entry);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }


    // manual entry dialog buttons
    public void enter_lat_dec_deg(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ManuallyEnterNumbers.class);

        button_pressed = "lat_dec_deg";

        intent.putExtra("Button pressed", button_pressed);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                double result = data.getDoubleExtra("returnData", 0.0d);

                if (result < -180 || result > 180) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Value outside range - Range is -180 to 180", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    DecimalFormat var = new DecimalFormat("###.########");

                    Toast.makeText(this, var.format(result), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    disable_button(button_pressed);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void disable_button(String pressed_button) {
        Button dec_deg_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_lat_dec_deg);
        Button d_m_s_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_lat_deg_min_sec);

        if (pressed_button != null) {
            if (pressed_button == "lat_dec_deg" || button_pressed == "lat_d_m_s") {
                dec_deg_button.setEnabled(false);
                d_m_s_button.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }

}

   /*    
    public void enter_lat_d_m_s (View v) {

    }

    public void enter_lon_dec_deg(View v) {

    }

    public void enter_lon_d_m_s(View v) {

    }
*/
```

And the called activity

```
    package com.example.david.gpstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by david on 06/03/16.
 */
public class ManuallyEnterNumbers extends Activity {

    private EditText input;

    private String inValue;

    private double decimal_input;

    private Bundle extras;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.manually_enter_numbers);

        extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            String buttonPressed = extras.getString("Button pressed");

            if (buttonPressed.contentEquals(buttonPressed) ) {
                ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.enter_decimal_number)).setHint("Decimal degrees of Latitude");

                TextView title_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.manual_entry_hint);
                title_text.setText("Please enter the decimal Latitude");

                TextView hint_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.manual_entry_hint);
                hint_text.setText("(Negative is South)");

            }
        }

        get_input();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
//        get_input();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

//        get_input();
     }


        public void get_input() {

            input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_decimal_number);

            input.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener(){
                @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        // do stuff here

                        inValue = input.getText().toString();

                        if (inValue.isEmpty()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter a value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            // some input
                            decimal_input = Double.parseDouble(inValue);

                            Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
                            returnIntent.putExtra("returnData", decimal_input);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                            finish();


                        }

                    }
                    return true;
                }

            });


/*
            Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("returnData", decimal_input);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
*/
    }



}
```

I hope that this helps you out a bit.

```
                   David.
```